# ExpiresByType except certain paths

Tags: apache

I've the following configuration for caching on client side:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "modification plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 2 weeks"
</IfModule>
```

However, there are some files as for example the visitor profile which I don't want to be cached, as the visitor can modify it. Because the modifications are through database, the file modification date does not change, therefore the "modification plus 2 weeks" would not work.

I wondering if is there any way to prevent some paths of being cached. I tried adding the following meta tags to the html files that I don't want being cached:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But some browsers would not even download the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Apache config after the above config to prevent the /login path from being cached:

```
#Do not cache these files
<Location /login >
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache" 
</Location>
```

Add a similar set of config for all the paths you don't want to cache.